# how can I add a button to a sublist in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I've created a script that adds a button to the work order in Netsuite. I can get the button to show up on the form but I'd like to show it on the related records subtab. I've tried the following code but I cannot get it to show up, what am I missing?

```
            //add the button to the work related records
            rr_sublist = form.getSublist({
                id: "recmachcustrecord_custom_wo_link"
            });

            rr_sublist.addButton({
                id : 'custpage_generate_MAC',
                label : 'Generate MAC',
                functionName : `generateMACNumbersFunction("${assemblyItem}", "${quantity}", "${tran_id}")`
            });
```